# Riemann Integrability Questions

Tags: derivatives, continuity, examples-counterexamples, riemann-integration

For each of the following sentences, we assume $f$ is
Riemann integrable on $[a, b]$ and $F$ is the function on $[a, b]$ defined by
$$
F(x)=\int_a^x f(t) \, \mathrm{d} t
$$
Determine whether the following statements are true or not:

(a) If $F$ is differentiable at $c \in(a, b)$, then $f$ is continuous at $c$.

(b) There exists $c \in[a, b]$ such that
$$
\frac{F(b)-F(a)}{b-a}=f(c)
$$

Regarding the first part, my guess was to provide the piece-wise function $f$ which could be differentiable on open subinterval but become discontinuous at some point of this interval. For instance, define a function $f$ on $[-1,1]$ by
$$
f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
-1, & -1<x<0 \\
0, & x=0 \\
1, & 0<x<1
\end{array}\right.
$$

Then, $F(x)$ would be differentiable at any point other than $0$, whereas there may exist some point besides the zero for which $f$ is discontinuous there. Are there any insightful suggestions on how to proceed further, especially with the second part?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both statements are false.

(a) Take$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&[-1,1]&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R\\&x&\mapsto&\begin{cases}0&\text{ if }x\ne0\\1&\text{ if }x=0.\end{cases}\end{array}$$Then $F(x)=0$ for every $x\in[-1,1]$. So, $F$ is differentiable everywhere, but $f$ is discontinuous at $0$.

(b) Take$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&[0,1]&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R\\&x&\mapsto&\begin{cases}2x&\text{ if }x\ne\frac12\\0&\text{ if }x=\frac12.\end{cases}\end{array}$$Then $F(x)=x^2$ for every $x\in[-1,1]$. Therefore$$\frac{F(1)-F(0)}{1-0}=1,$$but $1$ is not in the range of $f$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I have been wondering the motivation of such a counterexample: how did you manage to come up with such a detailed counterexample? Do you always seek such specific functions to illustrate whether some statements are wrong or not

Comment: Moreover, I was also wondering whether my constructed function was also working or not - could you suggest or approve any insights about that part as well?

Comment: Yes. When I try to prove that statements like these are false, I look for specific counter-examples. And your $f$ does not work, since $F$ is *not* differentiable at $0$. You should aim at a function which is differentiable everywhere.

Comment: I am wondering how did you manage to come up with the function which managed to be differentiable at every point? Should one just look for step functions if we want to come up with similarly related counterexamples?!

Comment: No. The function$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&[-1,1]&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R\\&x&\mapsto&\begin{cases}0&\text{ if }x<0\\1&\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}\end{array}$$is a step function, but then$$F(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{ if }x<0\\x&\text{ otherwise,}\end{cases}$$which is not differentiable.

Answer (score 2):

For the part b),

take

$$f(x)=-1\;\; \text{ if }\;\; -1\le x\le 0$$
and
$$f(x)=1\;\; \text{ if }\;\; 0<x\le 1$$

it is clear that

$$\frac{F(1)-F(-1)}{2}=$$
$$\displaystyle{\frac{\int_{-1}^1f(x)dx}{2}=0}$$

but
$$\forall c\in(-1,1)\;\; f(c)\ne 0$$